Why is my form submit button not clicking?
I'm new to NextJs and I'm working on an ecommerce project. I have a checkout page that requests delivery info, which has a button that when clicked displays a form in a modal display. Whenever I click on the submit button, nothing happens, its almost like the form isn't recognizes my button click.
Below is a snippet of the code
"use client"
///Order Form Modal component

///Libraries -->
import styles from "./orderFormModal.module.scss"
import { useModalBackgroundStore, useOrderFormModalStore, useClientInfoStore } from "@/config/store";
import { MouseEvent, useState, ChangeEvent, useEffect, FormEvent } from "react";
import Loading from "@/components/loadingCircle/Circle";
import CloseIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Close";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { ICart, IClientInfo, ICountry, ICustomerSpec  } from "@/config/interfaces";
import { countryList } from "@/config/database";
import { notify, setItem, getItem } from "@/config/clientUtils";
import validator from "validator";
import { domainName, cartName, deliveryName, capitalizeFirstLetter, findStateWithZeroExtraDeliveryPercent, round, sleep } from "@/config/utils"

///Commencing the code 

/**
 * @title Order Form Modal Component
 * @returns The Order Form Modal component
 */
const OrderFormModal = () => {
    const setModalBackground = useModalBackgroundStore(state => state.setModalBackground);
    const setOrderFormModal = useOrderFormModalStore(state => state.setOrderFormModal);
    const orderFormModal = useOrderFormModalStore(state => state.modal);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const clientInfo = useClientInfoStore(state => state.info)
    const router = useRouter()
    const [fullName, setFullName] = useState<string | undefined>("")
    const [phoneNumber1, setPhoneNumber1] = useState<string>("")
    const [phoneNumber2, setPhoneNumber2] = useState<string>("")
    const [emailAddress, setEmailAddress] = useState<string>("")
    const [country, setCountry] = useState<string>("")
    const [countryInfo, setCountryInfo] = useState<ICountry | undefined>()
    const [state, setState] = useState<string | undefined>("")
    const [postalCode, setPostalCode] = useState<string>("")
    const [deliveryAddress, setDeliveryAddress] = useState<string>("")
    const [countryCode1, setCountryCode1] = useState<ICountry>()
    const [countryCode2, setCountryCode2] = useState<ICountry>()
    const [dropList1, setDropList1] = useState(false)
    const [dropList2, setDropList2] = useState(false)
    const [extraDeliveryFee, setExtraDeliveryFee] = useState<number>(0) //Unit is in USD
    const cart_ = getItem(cartName)
    const [cart, setCart] = useState<ICart | null>(cart_)

    ///This function is triggered when the background of the modal is clicked
    const closeModal = async (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, globalThis.MouseEvent>): Promise<void> => {
        e.preventDefault()

        //router.push("/")
        setOrderFormModal(false)
        await sleep(0.2)
        setModalBackground(false)
        //console.log("modal closed")
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        //getClientInfo()
        
        if (clientInfo && clientInfo?.country) {
            //setCountryCode1(() => clientInfo.country)
            console.log("Loc: ", clientInfo)
            if (!countryCode1 && !countryCode2 && !country) {
                setCountryCode1(() => clientInfo.country)
                setCountryCode2(() => clientInfo.country)

                const country = clientInfo.country.name?.common as unknown as string
                setCountry(() => country)
                const info = countryList.find(country => country.name?.common === clientInfo?.country?.name?.common)
                console.log("Country: ", info)
                setCountryInfo(() => info)

                const state_ = findStateWithZeroExtraDeliveryPercent(info)
                setState(() => state_?.name)
                //setExtraDeliveryFee(() => state_?.extraDeliveryPercent as unknown as number)
            }
        }
    }, [clientInfo, countryInfo]);

    ///This function saves the delivery info
    // const saveDeliveryInfo = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>):Promise<void> => {
    //     e.preventDefault()
    //     console.log("Seen")

    //     if (!fullName) {
    //         notify("error", "Fullname is required")
    //         return
    //     } else if (!phoneNumber1) {
    //         notify("error", "Phone number is required")
    //         return
    //     } else if (!emailAddress) {
    //         notify("error", "Email address is required")
    //         return
    //     } else if (!validator.isEmail(emailAddress)) {
    //         notify("error", "Email address is not valid")
    //         return
    //     } else if (!country) {
    //         notify("error", "Country address is required")
    //         return
    //     } else if (!state) {
    //         notify("error", "State is required")
    //         return
    //     } else if (!postalCode) {
    //         notify("error", "Postal code is required")
    //         return
    //     } else if (!deliveryAddress) {
    //         notify("error", "Delivery address is required")
    //         return
    //     }

    //     setIsLoading(() => true)

    //     try {
    //         const customerSpec: ICustomerSpec = {fullName, email: emailAddress, phoneNumbers: [`${countryCode1?.dial_code}-${phoneNumber1}`, `${countryCode2?.dial_code}-${phoneNumber2}`], country, state, deliveryAddress, postalCode}
    //         setItem(deliveryName, customerSpec)
    //     } catch (error) {
    //         console.log("Save Delivery Error: ", error)
    //     }

    //     setIsLoading(false)
    //     setOrderFormModal(false)
    //     await sleep(0.1)
    //     setModalBackground(false)
    // }

    const saveDeliveryInfo = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>):Promise<void> => {
        console.log("Seen")
    }

    //This handles the handle change effect
  const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>, label: string) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (label === "country") {
        setCountry(e.target.value);

        const countryInfo_ = countryList.find(country => country.name?.common === country) as unknown as ICountry
        setCountryInfo(() => countryInfo_)
    } else if (label === "state") {
        if (cart && clientInfo?.country?.currency?.exchangeRate) {
            setState(e.target.value)
            const symbol = clientInfo.country.currency.symbol
        
            //Checking if the state has extraDeliveryPercent and notifying the client
            const state_ = countryInfo?.states?.find(states => states.name === e.target.value)
            
            if (state_?.extraDeliveryPercent === 0) {
                    const total = round((cart.totalPrice - cart.totalDiscount + cart.deliveryFee) * clientInfo.country.currency.exchangeRate, 1).toLocaleString("en-US")
                    notify("info", `Your total order amount is ${symbol}${total}`)
                
                
            } else {
                if (state_?.extraDeliveryPercent && cart?.deliveryFee) {
                    const extraDeliveryFee = (state_?.extraDeliveryPercent / 100) * cart?.deliveryFee
                    setExtraDeliveryFee(() => extraDeliveryFee)
                    const formatExtraDeliveryFee = round(extraDeliveryFee * clientInfo.country.currency.exchangeRate, 1).toLocaleString("en-US")
                    const total = round((cart.totalPrice - cart.totalDiscount + cart.deliveryFee + extraDeliveryFee) * clientInfo.country.currency.exchangeRate, 1).toLocaleString("en-US")
                    notify("info", `Delivery to ${e.target.value} gets an additional delivery charge of ${symbol}${formatExtraDeliveryFee}. Your total order amount is ${symbol}${total}`)
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

  ///This function is triggered when the choose code is clicked
  const chooseCode = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, globalThis.MouseEvent>, position: string | number, country: ICountry) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    console.log("Position: ", typeof position)
    if (position === "1") {
        setDropList1(() => false)
        //console.log("Country1: ", country)
        setCountryCode1(() => country)
        //console.log("Country code: ", countryCode1)
    } else if (position === "2") {
        setDropList2(() => false)
        //console.log("Country2: ", country)
        setCountryCode2(() => country)
        //console.log("Country code: ", countryCode2)
    }
  }

  ///This function is trigerred when the show drop down is clicked
  const showDropDown = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, globalThis.MouseEvent>, position: string | number) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (position === "1") {
        setDropList1(!dropList1)
        //console.log("drop 1")
    } else if (position === "2") {
        //console.log("drop 2")
        setDropList2(!dropList2)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={`${styles.main} ${orderFormModal ? styles.activeState : styles.inactiveState}`} >
        <div className={styles.modal_head}>
            <button onClick={(e) => closeModal(e)} >
                <CloseIcon className={styles.icon} />
            </button>
        </div>
        <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={(e) => saveDeliveryInfo(e)} id="form" action="">
                    <label htmlFor="fullname">Fullname</label>
                    <br />
                    <input id="fullname" placeholder="Surname Firstname Othernames" type="text" onChange={(e) => setFullName(capitalizeFirstLetter(e.target.value))}
                        value={fullName}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <label htmlFor="number1">Phone Number</label> 
                    <br /> 
                    <div className={styles.number_form} id="number1">
                        <div className={styles.dial_code_container}>
                                <button className={styles.dial_code} onClick={(e) => showDropDown(e, "1")}>
                                <Image 
                                    className={styles.img}
                                    src={countryCode1?.flag?.src as unknown as string}
                                    alt=""
                                    width={countryCode1?.flag?.width as unknown as number}
                                    height={countryCode1?.flag?.height as unknown as number}
                                />
                                <span>{countryCode1?.dial_code}</span>
                                <span className={`${styles.arrow} ${dropList1 ? styles.active_arrow : ""}`}>{">"}</span>
                            </button>
                            <div className={`${styles.dial_code_option}`} style={{ display: dropList1 ? "flex" : "none"}}>
                                {countryList.map((country, cid) => (
                                    <button key={cid} onClick={(e) => chooseCode(e, "1", country)}>
                                        <Image
                                            className={styles.img} 
                                            src={country.flag?.src as unknown as string}
                                            alt=""
                                            width={country.flag?.width as unknown as number}
                                            height={country.flag?.height as unknown as number}
                                        />
                                        <span>{country.name?.common}</span>
                                        <span>{country.dial_code}</span>
                                    </button>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className={styles.number_input}>
                            <input 
                                placeholder="123456789"
                                type="tel"
                                onChange={(e) => setPhoneNumber1(e.target.value)}
                                value={phoneNumber1}
                            />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    
                    <label htmlFor="number2">Other number (optional)</label>
                    <br />
                    <div className={styles.other_number_form} id="number2">
                        <div className={styles.dial_code_container}>
                            {countryCode2 ? (
                                <button className={styles.dial_code} onClick={(e) => showDropDown(e, "2")}>
                                <Image
                                    className={styles.img} 
                                    src={countryCode2.flag?.src as unknown as string}
                                    alt=""
                                    width={countryCode2.flag?.width as unknown as number}
                                    height={countryCode2.flag?.height as unknown as number}
                                />
                                <span>{countryCode2.dial_code}</span>
                                <span className={`${styles.arrow} ${dropList2 ? styles.active_arrow : ""}`}>{">"}</span>
                            </button>
                            ) : (
                                <></>
                            )}
                            <div className={`${styles.dial_code_option}`} style={{ display: dropList2 ? "flex" : "none"}}>
                                {countryList.map((country, cid) => (
                                    <button key={cid} onClick={(e) => chooseCode(e, "2", country)}>
                                        <Image
                                            className={styles.img} 
                                            src={country.flag?.src as unknown as string}
                                            alt=""
                                            width={country.flag?.width as unknown as number}
                                            height={country.flag?.height as unknown as number}
                                        />
                                        <span>{country.name?.common}</span>
                                        <span>{country.dial_code}</span>
                                    </button>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className={styles.number_input}>
                            <input 
                                placeholder="123456789"
                                type="tel"
                                onChange={(e) => setPhoneNumber2(e.target.value)}
                                value={phoneNumber2}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label>
                    <br />
                    <input
                        id="email"
                        placeholder="example@mail.com"
                        type="email"
                        onChange={(e) => setEmailAddress(e.target.value)}
                        value={emailAddress}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <label htmlFor="country">Country</label>
                    <br />
                    {countryCode1 ? (
                        <select value={country} onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "country")} id="country">
                        {countryList.map((country, cid) => (
                            <option value={country.name?.common} key={cid}>{country.name?.common}</option>
                        ))}
                    </select>
                    ) : (
                        <></>
                    )}
                    
                    <br />
                    <label htmlFor="state">State</label>
                    <br />
                    {countryInfo && countryInfo.states ? (
                        <select value={state} onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "state")} id="state">
                            {countryInfo.states.map((state, sid) => (
                                <option value={state.name} key={sid}>{state.name}</option>
                            ))}
                        </select>
                    ) : (
                        <input
                            placeholder="State of residence"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={(e) => setState(capitalizeFirstLetter(e.target.value))}
                            value={state}
                        />
                    )}
                    <br />
                    <label htmlFor="postal">Postal Code</label>
                    <br />
                    <input
                        id="postal"
                        placeholder="Postal code"
                        type="text"
                        onChange={(e) => setPostalCode(e.target.value)}
                        value={postalCode}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <label htmlFor="deliveryAddress">Delivery Address</label>
                    <br />
                    <input
                        id="deliveryAddress"
                        placeholder="Address of delivery"
                        type="textarea"
                        onChange={(e) => setDeliveryAddress(e.target.value)}
                        value={deliveryAddress}
                    />
                    <br />
                    
                    <button className={styles.order_button} type="submit" id="button">
                        {isLoading ? (
                            <Loading width="20px" height="20px" />
                        ) : (
                            <>
                                <span>Submit</span>
                            </>
                        )}
                    </button>
                </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default OrderFormModal;

I have tried surfing the internet for answers but have all been in vain, the button still doesn't click.
Please I'm out of options, I need help with a solution. Thanks.

I haven't used form actions yet to know exactly how they work, but I'm suspicious about the action="" on the form when your intended logic is in the onSubmit. Does anything change if you remove that?

Yeah, i did remove and even added method="POST", still yet nothing

Are you seeing any sort of console log message on button click?

don't you see the "Seen" message on the console when hitting the submit button?

no, I don't see the Seen. Its like the function isn't triggering at all

I was able to work around it. Instead of using the onSubmit event I used the onClick event on the button tag and redirected it to the same function. Can't still seem to figure out why the onSubmit event isn't working, that was worked for me
<form className={styles.form}>
                    <label >
                        Fullname
                        <input placeholder="Surname Firstname Othernames" type="text" onChange={(e) => setFullName(capitalizeFirstLetter(e.target.value))}
                            value={fullName}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <label>
                        Phone Number
                        <div className={styles.number_form}>
                        <div className={styles.dial_code_container}>
                                <button className={styles.dial_code} onClick={(e) => showDropDown(e, "1")}>
                                <Image 
                                    className={styles.img}
                                    src={countryCode1?.flag?.src as unknown as string}
                                    alt=""
                                    width={countryCode1?.flag?.width as unknown as number}
                                    height={countryCode1?.flag?.height as unknown as number}
                                />
                                <span>{countryCode1?.dial_code}</span>
                                <span className={`${styles.arrow} ${dropList1 ? styles.active_arrow : ""}`}>{">"}</span>
                            </button>
                            <div className={`${styles.dial_code_option}`} style={{ display: dropList1 ? "flex" : "none"}}>
                                {countryList.map((country, cid) => (
                                    <button key={cid} onClick={(e) => chooseCode(e, "1", country)}>
                                        <Image
                                            className={styles.img} 
                                            src={country.flag?.src as unknown as string}
                                            alt=""
                                            width={country.flag?.width as unknown as number}
                                            height={country.flag?.height as unknown as number}
                                        />
                                        <span>{country.name?.common}</span>
                                        <span>{country.dial_code}</span>
                                    </button>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className={styles.number_input}>
                            <input 
                                placeholder="123456789"
                                type="tel"
                                onChange={(e) => setPhoneNumber1(e.target.value)}
                                value={phoneNumber1}
                            />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    </label> 
                    {/* <br />  */}
                    <label>
                        Other number (optional)
                        <div className={styles.other_number_form}>
                        <div className={styles.dial_code_container}>
                            {countryCode2 ? (
                                <button className={styles.dial_code} onClick={(e) => showDropDown(e, "2")}>
                                <Image
                                    className={styles.img} 
                                    src={countryCode2.flag?.src as unknown as string}
                                    alt=""
                                    width={countryCode2.flag?.width as unknown as number}
                                    height={countryCode2.flag?.height as unknown as number}
                                />
                                <span>{countryCode2.dial_code}</span>
                                <span className={`${styles.arrow} ${dropList2 ? styles.active_arrow : ""}`}>{">"}</span>
                            </button>
                            ) : (
                                <></>
                            )}
                            <div className={`${styles.dial_code_option}`} style={{ display: dropList2 ? "flex" : "none"}}>
                                {countryList.map((country, cid) => (
                                    <button key={cid} onClick={(e) => chooseCode(e, "2", country)}>
                                        <Image
                                            className={styles.img} 
                                            src={country.flag?.src as unknown as string}
                                            alt=""
                                            width={country.flag?.width as unknown as number}
                                            height={country.flag?.height as unknown as number}
                                        />
                                        <span>{country.name?.common}</span>
                                        <span>{country.dial_code}</span>
                                    </button>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className={styles.number_input}>
                            <input 
                                placeholder="123456789"
                                type="tel"
                                onChange={(e) => setPhoneNumber2(e.target.value)}
                                value={phoneNumber2}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </label>
                    {/* <br /> */}
                    <label>
                        Email Address
                        <input
                            placeholder="example@mail.com"
                            type="email"
                            onChange={(e) => setEmailAddress(e.target.value)}
                            value={emailAddress}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <label>
                        Country
                        {countryCode1 ? (
                            <select value={country} onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "country")}>
                            {countryList.map((country, cid) => (
                                <option value={country.name?.common} key={cid}>{country.name?.common}</option>
                            ))}
                        </select>
                        ) : (
                            <></>
                        )}
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <label>
                        State
                        {countryInfo && countryInfo.states ? (
                            <select value={state} onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "state")}>
                                {countryInfo.states.map((state, sid) => (
                                    <option value={state.name} key={sid}>{state.name}</option>
                                ))}
                            </select>
                        ) : (
                            <input
                                placeholder="State of residence"
                                type="text"
                                onChange={(e) => setState(capitalizeFirstLetter(e.target.value))}
                                value={state}
                            />
                        )}
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <label>
                        Postal Code
                        <input
                            placeholder="Postal code"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={(e) => setPostalCode(e.target.value)}
                            value={postalCode}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <label>
                        Delivery Address
                        <input
                            placeholder="Address of delivery"
                            type="textarea"
                            onChange={(e) => setDeliveryAddress(e.target.value)}
                            value={deliveryAddress}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <button className={styles.order_button} onClick={(e) => saveDeliveryInfo(e)}>
                        {isLoading ? (
                            <Loading width="20px" height="20px" />
                        ) : (
                            <>
                                <span>Submit</span>
                            </>
                        )}
                    </button>
                </form>

